# Kernel booting error - Can I get the log?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I replaced the kernel with the new one I built.

Unfortunately, the system hangs during the booting process of the kernel.

The booting messages shown just in few seconds, is that possible to get these booting messages ( logs ) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are stored in **/var/log/kern.log**

Comment: But the system hangs during the boot, how can I get this log ?

Comment: If you are using GRUB hold shift while  boot and from there choose recovery and enter to a root terminal or just use a live cd

Comment: This will work only in case if userspace (systemd) has been managed to start. Otherwise serial console or netconsole is the way to get 'em.